# SQL inner join performance issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance

I got this SQL query

```
SELECT clicks, 
       songs.uid, 
       songs.title, 
       songs.artist      AS artistUID, 
       artists.name      AS artist, 
       songs.tag         AS tagUID, 
       tags.name         AS tag, 
       songinalbum.album AS albumUID, 
       albums.title      AS album, 
       albums.cover 
FROM   songs 
       INNER JOIN stats 
               ON stats.uid = songs.uid 
       INNER JOIN artists 
               ON artists.uid = songs.artist 
       INNER JOIN tags 
               ON tags.uid = songs.tag 
       INNER JOIN songinalbum 
               ON songinalbum.song = songs.uid 
       INNER JOIN albums 
               ON albums.uid = songinalbum.album 
WHERE  stats.type = 'songs' 
       AND albums.completed = 1 
ORDER  BY clicks DESC 
LIMIT  20 offset 0
```

The execution time of this query is about **13.5 seconds** but when i remove `INNER JOIN tags ON tags.uid = songs.tag` and in the select statement `songs.tag AS tagUID, tags.name AS tag` then the execution time is reduced to **0.31 seconds**. How is that possible?

Here is the structure of the tags table:
[image]

**EDIT**:
Here is how the song table looks like, those uid's refers to the corresponding entry in the album/artist/tag table etc. uid's are used to prevent bots from crawling my website, beacause the content is available under `https://www.url.de/song/{{uid}}` if i would use the id the bot could increment the id just by one to crawl the hole site.
  [image]

Comment: Make sure you have indexes on `tags.uid` and `songs.tag`.

Comment: Also make sure that songs.tag is a VARCHAR. If one is an int and the other is a VARCHAR that'll kill indexing.

Comment: Any questions about performance really need to include an execution plan, so that we can verify the guess about "you need an index" (although that's often the common reason).  Side note: I'm assuming your `WHERE` clause is being generated dynamically.  Otherwise, those two conditions properly belong with their originating table's `JOIN ... ON` clause (in most cases the optimizer effectively does this for you, this is just for clarity).  Use the `WHERE` clause for conditions referencing only the table referenced in `FROM` (and for some `LEFT JOIN` tricks).

Comment: Why would songs.tag have the uid instead of the id of the tags table.  In fact, what useful purpose does tags.uid actually have?

Comment: @DanBracuk I think you just pointed to something that all of us are thinking.

Comment: @nimmi Can you try using EXPLAIN and put the output into the question?

Comment: @DanBracuk Songs/Albums/Artists and Tags have uid's because on my website every individual Song/Album/Artist/Tag is accessible trough https://url.de/song/{{uid}}. The uid prevents the user to crawl the website, if i use the id instead the could increment the id everytime and could crawl through every single entry. So it is a security measure.

Answer (score 0):

- `id` seems to be unused and unnecessary in many of the tables; get rid of it.
- Change to `PRIMARY KEY(uid)` since it seems to be serving that purpose.
- Be sure that `uid` is `CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATION ascii_bin`.
- How much RAM?  What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?  How big is the entire dataset?  If these are not good sizes, you *will* have performance problems as the dataset grows.  (UUIDs are inefficient.)
- It may be possible to move the `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` into a subquery to get 20 rows *before* doing all the `JOINs`; this will speed things up.  But I can't be more specific until I know which table `clicks` is in.